# SAP JCo SAML authentication

Tags: java, saml, saprfc, sapjco3

I need to support SAML authentication in one of my applications connecting to SAP system using SAP JCo Library and couldn't find any related articles demonstrating the capability of JCo. Does anyone have any experience with that?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no feature at SAP ABAP application server side for doing an RFC logon with SAML authentication. And the SAP Java Connector cannot offer a logon mechanism for what is actually not there. So this is not supported yet.

As far as I know, logging on with SAML authentication is currently only offered via HTTP/HTTPS. SAP JCo is for RFC only.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your response, it's strange because I found these: https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Security/Single+Sign-On+with+SAML+2.0.  https://docs.idaptive.com/Content/Applications/AppsWeb/SAPNetWeaver_ASJava.htm   https://blogs.sap.com/2017/12/01/enabling-the-saml-2.0-service-provider-in-sap-netweaver-abap/

Comment: It's not true. SAML authentication between AS ABAP and AS Java systems [have been existed for a long time](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nwes72/helpdata/en/3b/0c4b428f96ab53e10000000a1550b0/frameset.htm), at least Netweaver 7.2. You are making over-generalization (SAML is not supported by JCo = SAML is not supported by AS ABAP at all)

Comment: @Suncatcher: I did not say what you implied! I said "SAML is not supported via RFC". Read again! What do you think which protocol is used in your answer? And what did I say about HTTP/HTTPS?

Comment: @ecommerceintern : Your links don't contain wrong info but refer to the ICF which serves the HTTP/HTTPS protocol. But your question was about using SAP JCo which implies that the RFC protocol shall be used. Unfortunately ABAP application servers don't support a SAML assertion ticket logon via RFC. I assume that maybe once this would be offered in the future, it will also find its way into the SAP JCo soon afterwards. I don't know if SAP already announced such a feature.

Comment: Got it so it's a no go for the moment. Thanks for the support!